# PHP - File-Uploader

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to create a file-uploader with php.
Does anybody know where the problem is. I am writing this code for the 3rd time, but it does not work...
Can anybody help me???
Thank you!!!

HTML-File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>File Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="upload_files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP-File:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file['file_tmp'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg');

        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
            if ($file_error === 0) {
                $file_new_name = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_dir = 'uploads/' . $file_new_name;

                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_dir)) {
                    echo $file_dir;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: And what exactly is wrong? What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error!!! That is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Check your php error log (or webserver error log) perhaps you can find some clues there. Perhaps directory permission issues or something. You can also explicitly set the error reporting in your script to ALL (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done mistake here.. `enctype="multipart/formdata"`

Change this to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload_files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Check This [File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)